# Fetch post response as html but also with status

Tags: javascript, text, fetch, status

I have a fetch call to an API. I need both `status` and the HTML response.

```js
fetch('api/post/email', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.text());
  console.log(response.body);

  if (response.status == 200) {
    console.log(response.status);
  } else {
    console.log(response.status);
  }
});
```

**I get this results from above:**

```
Promise {<pending>}
ReadableStream {locked: true}
404
```

The last one `status` is fine, but...

**What is the easiest way to get the body or the HTML results from the API with fetch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
fetch('api/post/email', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then((response) => {
  response.text().then(re => {
   console.log(re);
  });
  console.log(response.body);

  if (response.status == 200) {
    console.log(response.status);
  } else {
    console.log(response.status);
  }
});
```

Response.text() returns a promise so you have to handle it like it's suposed to be handled. (passing in a callback) after that you can log it , inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

The simples way I can think of is using async/await.

Note: `response.text()` returns a promise that resolves to the text.

```
fetch('api/post/email', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(async (response) => {
  const text = await response.text();
  if (response.status == 200) {
    console.log(response.status);
  } else {
    console.log(response.status);
  }
  console.log(text);
});
```